# Formulas for compressibility of solids (physics)

Tags: classical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formulas for compressibility of solids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37571/formulas-for-compressibility-of-solids)

I have a question which is technically a physics question, but since I have yet to find a good physics forum which accepts Latex, I am posting this question here.  I hope that's OK.

I am taking a course in mechanics this semester, as well as a course in reservoir physics.  Both courses have sections devoted to pressure/compressibility of solids, but the formulas look slightly different, so I wondered if they really mean the same or not.

In my mechanics class I am told that:

$$\Delta P = B \left(\frac{- \Delta V}{V_0}\right)$$

Where $B$ is a constant known as the **bulk modulus** of a given material.

In my reservoir physics class I am presented with the formula:

$$c = -\frac{1}{V} \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_{T}$$

Where $c$ is referred to as **isothermal compressibility**.

So my question is - are these formulas basically the same, where $c = \frac{1}{B}$?  And if they are not the same, can someone please explain the difference to me?  I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.  I wasn't even aware of this site.  I will repost my question there, and the moderator may remove it from here.

Comment: @Kristian you can delete the question yourself, there's a delete link right below (physics) (classical-mechanics) at the end of the question.